# Clonezilla on normal running system

Tags: clonezilla, cloning

I only used Clonezilla on Live USB and tried to use it inside running Ubuntu 14.04 amd64,
so before installed it in usual way

```
apt-get install clonezilla
```

Then inserted source USB drive to clone started clonezilla as root
choosen disk to image mode, then clonezilla quit to terminal and asked to insert external USB device. It is not required for me to save image to external USB disk so I just pressed Enter,
then it thrown this error:

```
clonezilla 
Clonezilla mode is device-image
ocsroot device is local_dev
Preparing the mount point /home/partimag...
If you want to use USB device as a Clonezilla image repository, please\n * Insert     USB device into this machine *now*\n * Wait for about 5 secs \n * Press Enter key \nso that the OS can detect the USB device and later we can mount it as /home/partimag.
Press "Enter" to continue......
Informing the OS of partition table changes...
Mounting local dev as /home/partimag...
Excluding busy partition or disk...
"Box" is an unknown partition device. Program terminated!.
Press Enter to exit...
Unable to mount resource as /home/partimag.
Are you sure you want to continue?
[y/N] 
Program terminated!
```

How can i just define options in terminal without using not obvious clonezilla GUI ?
So for example like dd does:
dd if=/my/source of=/my/destination conv="someoptions"